# Вызов массива из другого файла с динамическим названием

Tags: python

нужно вызвать массив у которой рандомное название и при этом она содержится в другом файле

main.py

```
import random
import file

randnum = random.randint(1, 6)
position = file.cellsarr[testpos]
testpos = 0

if 'number' in position:
    print(file.randnum(1))#!!!!
```

file.py

```
test1 = ('number', ["01", 60000, 3500, 5000, 6500, 8000, 8000, 2000])
test2 = 'pass'
test3 = ('number', ["02", 65000, 4000, 5500, 7000, 8500, 10500, 2500])
test4 = 'pass'
test5 = ('number', ["03", 280000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 0, 25000])
test6 = ('number', ["04", 70000, 4500, 6000, 7500, 9000, 11000, 3000])

testarr = [cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4, cell5, cell6]
```

Код не правильный это мое видение как приьлизительно может выглядеть решение, код должен выводить значение 1 выпавшего списка к примеру, выпал список 3 и мне выведет 65000 или если выпадет 6 то мне выведет 70000, я не понимаю как это сделать, решение может быть не обязательно похожим на мое предложенное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
import random
import file

randnum = random.randrange(6)
arr = file.testarr[randnum]

if 'number' in arr:
    print(arr[1][1])
```